# Testing JPA java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.db.jpa.JPABase

Tags: java, maven, jpa, junit4

Im trying to test my JPA entities and have been following this tutorial:

http://eskatos.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/unit-test-jpa-entities-with-in-memory-database/

I have a tests running so far and they are all passing, however i get the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.db.jpa.JPABase
```

at runtime (for each of my tests )even though the tests run fully and pass,

Im using maven with JBOSS 7.1 and tried importing play-db 1.1 but this hasn't helped,

Can anybody help me out here?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use tools with external librarys you need to put this librarys into your lib/ folder inside your jboss directory or ear/war archive.

Comment: You can download it from http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.playframework/play/1.2.5/