# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.db.jpa.JPABase using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jpa, playframework

I keep getting the following error messages in the catalina.out log on tomcat 7 and i just cant find the source:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.db.jpa.JPABase
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:150)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
at my.task.task.model.RequestLogManager.add(RequestLogManager.java:44)
at my.task.task.control.RequestLogFilter.logRequest(RequestLogFilter.java:48)
at my.task.task.control.RequestLogFilter.doFilter(RequestLogFilter.java:31)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at my.task.task.control.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:26)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:269)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1773)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I iam using **hibernate 3** and **JSF 2** with **Mysql** server.
In no point i used the **play framework**.

the exception isn't causing persistence issues, all the transactions are commited in data base. so its actually more annoying then a problem, but i just cant stand having an error message without knowing the source and cleaning my logs.

the code causeing the error is:

```
public int add(RequestLogBean request) {
    if (request.getUserName() == null || request.getUserName().isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing request user name");
    }

    int result = -1;
    Session session = this.getFactory().openSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        result = (Integer) session.save(request);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch(HibernateException e) {         
        if(session.getTransaction() != null) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

at the `commit()`

I have looked into:
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199147/testing-jpa-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-play-db-jpa-jpabase)

but my case is different i'm not using jBoss but tomcat.
I added to my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.10.Final-patched-play-1.2.5</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

and i know for sure my maven dependencies are added to my classpath.

**What is `play.db.jpa.JPABase` Class used for?**

I read that it a base class for any jpa impl on play framework, but i dont even have it installed on my computer.....

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use Play, there is no reason to use an artefact with the groupId `com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.hibernate`. This is probably a version of hibernate-core that has been forked and modified to use with the Play framework.

Use the real hibernate core: [org.hibernate:hibernate-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core).

Comment: you were correct, I added it manually when i got the error and i guess it kind of stayed there.